# How to remove xmlns from child elements with FOR XML

Tags: t-sql, xml

I have a TSQL query that I use to generate a SOAP document. I am using two namespaces. Namely:
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ for "packaging" the soap document
- A custom one that describes the data contained within the body

Currently every single element including those in the body contain the soapnamespace reference which I don't need and want in there I only want it in the root element.

So my XML now looks like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns="soapenv" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pas="foobar">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns="soapenv" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pas="foobar" />
            <soapenv:Body xmlns="soapenv" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pas="foobar">
                    <pas:SomeObject xmlns="soapenv" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pas="foobar">
```

and I want it to look like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns="soapenv" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pas="foobar">
    <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                    <pas:SomeObject>
```

In the query I am currently using

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://foobar' as pas,
      'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as soapenv
      )
SELECT (SELECT '' FOR XML PATH('soapenv:Header'),type ),
etc...
FOR XML PATH('soapenv:Envelope'), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: Cross-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3242070/11683

Answer (score 5):

Vote on [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements) for a change of behavior.

You can use [for xml explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx) to build your XML instead.

Something like this:

```sql
;with DummyTable(id) as 
(
  select 1 union all
  select 2
)

select 1 as tag,
       0 as parent,
       'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soapenv:Envelope!1!xmlns:soapenv],
       'http://foobar' as [soapenv:Envelope!1!xmlns:pas],
        null as [pas:Child!2!pas:ID]
union all
select 2,
       1,
       null,
       null,
       id
from DummyTable       
for xml explicit
```

Result:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pas="http://foobar">
  <pas:Child pas:ID="1" />
  <pas:Child pas:ID="2" />
</soapenv:Envelope>
```